# Is Porn-Creep a medical condition? Addiction to pornography (for men) correlate to erectile dysfunction?

Tags: sociosexual-behavior, libido, erectile-dysfunction, orgasm-climax

Is Porn-Creep a medical condition? We all know that pornography can be highly addictive and can in many circumstances  ruin relationships. Does it correlate to erectile dysfunction for men and/or an inability for men to orgasm/reach climax? Or have a healthy libido?

Answer (score 4):

Let's start with your assumptions.  You say that "We all know that pornography can be highly addictive."  But in fact, porn addiction is **not** a recognized diagnosis in the Diagnostic and Statistical Manual of Mental Disorders.  In addition, in November 2016, the American Association of Sexuality Educators, Counselors and Therapists (AASECT) issued a position statement on sex / porn addiction which states that AASECT "does not find sufficient empirical evidence to support the classification of sex addiction or porn addiction as a mental health disorder." (See https://www.aasect.org/position-sex-addiction)

So no, the medical community does not agree that porn addiction is a real thing.

Now, let's consider the effect of porn viewing on ED.  A number of studies have shown a correlation between porn viewing and ED.  But correlation does *not* prove causation.  It may be that men with ED simply watch more porn.  (See https://edtreatment.info/does-porn-cause-ed-erectile-dysfunction/)

At the moment, I would say that this is an open question.  There is no clear evidence that watching porn causes ED.

Comment: +1 for a great answer, but for this:  *In addition, in November 2016, the American Association of Sexuality Educators, Counselors and Therapists (AASECT) issued a position statement on sex / porn addiction which states that AASECT "does not find sufficient empirical evidence to support the classification of sex addiction or porn addiction as a mental health disorder."* [citation needed]

Comment: Looks like [sex addiction is officially a mental disease now, according to WHO](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2018/07/09/sex-addiction-could-treated-nhs-afterworld-health-organization/): "*According to the WHO, compulsive sexual behaviour disorder is defined as an inability to control intense sexual urges leading to people neglecting their health despite often deriving no pleasure from being intimate.*"